# numpy dot product for tensors (3d times 2d)

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensor, numpy-einsum

Currently I use

```
Na = (3, 2, 4)
Nb = Na[1:]
A = np.arange(np.prod(Na)).reshape(Na)
b = np.arange(np.prod(Nb)).reshape(Nb)
```

I want to calculate:

[image: r_ik = sum_j(A_ijk * b_jk)]

```
r = np.empty((A.shape[0], A.shape[2])
for i in range(A.shape[2]):
    r[:, i] = np.dot(A[:, :, i], b[:, i])
```

In words: A is a "stack of 4 matrices" (shaped (3,2)), i.e. a 3d-array, b is a "stack of 4 vectors" (shaped (3,)), i.e. a 2d-array. The desired result is a "stack of 4 matrix-vector-products", i.e. a stack of vectors, i.e. again a 2d-array (shaped (3, 4)).

I had a medium-depth look to np.einsum and np.tensordot but any solution that I constructed with these was at least as long and less readable than my loop-solution.

However I think there should be a one-liner for that simple problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) didn't work for you. This *should* do the trick:

```
r = np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik', A, b)
```

I consider this to be very readable, because it exactly reflects the mathematical formula you've given in your question.

Comment: Indeed it works. I was confused by the formulation "Whenever a label is repeated, it is summed" (einsum docs). I want only one summation but `j` and `k` are repeated. Therefor I only tried `np.einsum('ijk,jl->ik', A, b)`

Comment: A few paragraphs further down says that `output` indexing, ` allows summing to be disallowed or forced when desired`.  Putting `k` in the output turns off its summation, and it just 'goes along for the ride'.